# Nhibernate: invoke stored procedure with CreateSqlQuery using already defined mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I Invoke a stored procedure using `ISession.CreateSQLQuery`.

Then I use

```
SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Article))).List<Article>().ToList()
```

The problem with this approach is that the `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` only maps the `Article` table to the `Article` class one to one.

```
public class Article : Entity
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleRepository : Repository<Article>, IArticleRepository
{
    private ISession _session;

    public ArticleRepository(ISession session) : base(session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public List<Article> GetByDescription(string description)
    {
        return _session
            .CreateSQLQuery("EXEC ArticlesByDescription :Description")
            .SetString("Description", description)
            .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Article)))
            .List<Article>().ToList();
    }
}
```

But my primary key on my `Article` table is called `ArticleId`, so that the `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` throws an exception.

> Could not find a setter for property 'ArticleId' in class
>   'Core.DomainModels.Article'

Is there a way of reusing the FluentNhibernateMapping when using `CreateSqlQuery`?

EDIT:

The [Nhibernate Documentation](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/23/populating-entities-from-stored-procedures-with-nhibernate.aspx) describes how you can use an already mapped entity with hbm files.

```
<sql-query name="GetProductsByCategoryId">
   <return class="Product" />
   exec dbo.GetProductsByCategoryId :CategoryId
</sql-query>
```

I really ask myself why is it not possible to do this just by code?!

Comment: In SP can you not do `select ArticleId as Id, ...`?

Comment: Of course, but this is really cumbersome. When I would use hbm files would then Nhibernate use the FluentNhMappings when I invoke a sp?

Comment: The problem is you inherit from `public class Entity` that expects Id in your resultset. The only other way is to create a ArticleDto

Comment: `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` is not clever enough to transform column names based on your mappings.

Comment: @Rippo yes. Is there another way of getting a typed result from a store procedure that uses the FNH mappings?

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of, btw its not a FNH problem rather a NH issue. To be fair a `SP` should populate a DTO as it is never really mutable.

Comment: I don't understand why I should use a DTO in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems not possible to use `ISession.CreateSQLQuery` and get a **mapped** entity back from the `ISession`.

What I do for now is using hbm files and FluentNhibernate mappings together.

Hbm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Core" namespace="Core.DomainModels">
  <sql-query name="ArticlesByDescription">
    <return class="Article" />
    EXEC ArticlesByDescription :Description
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

FluentNhibernate:

```
public class ArticleMapping : ClassMap<Article>
{
    public ArticleMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.ArticleId).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Description).UniqueKey("Article_Description_Unique");
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
public class ConfigurationFactory
{
    const string Database = "";
    const string Server = "";

    public static Configuration Build()
    {           
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
                c => c.Database(Database).TrustedConnection().Server(Server)))
            .Mappings(m =>
            {
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ArticleMapping>();
                m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ArticleMapping>();
            })
            //.ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaExport(c).Execute(true, true, false))
            .BuildConfiguration();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class ArticleRepository : Repository<Article>, IArticleRepository
{
    private ISession _session;

    public ArticleRepository(ISession session) : base(session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public List<Article> GetByDescription(string description)
    {
        return _session
            .GetNamedQuery("ArticlesByDescription")
            .SetString("Description", description)
            .List<Article>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using this code for mapping to entity in repository. I believe it would work for calling procedure also:

```
public IEnumerable<Address> Search(string query, int maxCount)
{
    return session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM address WHERE fts_col @@ plainto_tsquery('cs', :query) LIMIT :limit;")
        .AddEntity(typeof(Address)) // this is probably what you need to map to entity
        .SetString("query", query)
        .SetInt32("limit", maxCount)
        .List<Address>();
}
```